# commutativity of $\iota^*$ and ${\bar\partial}^*$ / $\mathcal G$ on smooth differential froms

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $(X,\omega_X)$ be a compact Kaehler manifold. Denote by  $\iota:Y\rightarrow X$ the natural embedding, where $Y$ is a submanifold in $X$. Recall that we have the
De Rham-Kodaira Hodge decomposition on smooth $(p,q)$-forms,
$$\mathcal I=\bar\partial{\bar\partial}*\mathcal G+{\bar\partial}^*{\bar\partial}\mathcal G+\mathcal H,$$
where $\mathcal I$ is the identity operator, $\mathcal H$ is the harmonic projection, and $\mathcal G$ (resp. ${\bar\partial}^*$) is the Green operator (resp. the adjoint of $\bar\partial$-operator) with respect to the (induced) metric on the corresponding (sub)manifold.

My question is that consider the following special pull-back $\iota^*$, do we have the following commutativity on $(p,q)$-forms:

$$\iota^*\circ{\bar\partial}_X^*={\bar\partial}_Y^*\circ\iota^*\,;\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\iota^*\mathcal G_X=\mathcal G_Y\circ\iota^*\,?\tag{2}\label{2}$$

Here are some thoughts of mine:
Regarding \eqref{1}, recall that ${\bar\partial}^*=-*\circ{\partial}\circ *$, so \eqref{1} holds if $\iota^*$ and $*$ can commute. However, I don't know how to prove this part... (is this property correct?)

Regarding \eqref{2}, in my opinion, it holds if we have \eqref{1}, here is the argument:
Let $\phi\in A^{p,q}(X)$, then
$$\phi=\mathcal H(\phi)+\Delta_{\bar\partial}\mathcal G(\phi),$$
thus,
$$\iota^*\phi=\iota^*\mathcal H(\phi)+\iota^*\Delta_{\bar\partial}\mathcal G_X(\phi)=\mathcal H(\iota^*\phi)+\Delta_{\bar\partial}\underline{\iota^*\mathcal G_X(\phi)}.$$
The underline thus equals to $\mathcal G_Y\iota^*\phi$ thanks to the uniqueness.

**Question 3**: for this part, am I right?

Any suggests will be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: I think (1) is not true: If $X$ has dimension $n$, take a non-constant $(n-1,n)$-form $\alpha$. Its pullback to $Y$ will be zero, but if $Y$ is a hypersurface then we should be able to arrange for the pullback of $\bar\partial_X^* \alpha$ to not be zero. I don't have much of an intuition for the Green operator, but I would expect some obstruction terms from the curvature of $Y$ in $X$ for (2) to be true.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon, thanks a lot. Your example for (1) is motivating.